# asp:HyperLink not pass by querystring

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am using a asp:HyperLink as it gave me the ability to open up the linked page in a new tab.
One issue I am facing with this control is that as the info I need to pass is confidential, I do not want to do something like:

```
    <asp:HyperLink ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" Target="_blank" NavigateUrl= '<%# String.Format("SPage.aspx?val={0}", Eval("Uid")) %>'>View/Print</asp:HyperLink>
```

In other words, I do not want to pass info such that it is viewable by the user. Is there any other way around this. Is there any other control that can easily open up the link on another page and yet give me the ability to pass info without querystring (as this will be viewable). My main concern is that I am passing CONFIDENTIAL info in the querystring and as such do not want to user to view it.

Comment: You cannot make the user send a request without letting the user see the request.

Comment: You can try encrypting the Uid before sent to the client, decrypting it when a postback has been made

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos encode is not decryption

Comment: Why not store the information you need in a session and when loading the SPage.aspx, extract data from the session stored previously?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you *can* do :

From the server side   :

```
LinkButton2.NavigateUrl="~/SPage.aspx?uid=" +Uri.EscapeDataString(Utils.Encrypt(Uid)); //Utils.encrypt is your encryption function
```

Users will see it , but they won't understand nothing from it.

Later , on your page  :

`var myValue =  Utils.Descrypt(Uri.UnescapeDataString(request["uid"]));`

Comment: Might you know what the namespace is for Utils.Encrypt. I am not able to get it. I tried: System.Security.Cryptography;

Comment: Its just a dummy invented library name . You can encrypt it however you like . The uri library however is a real dot net lib. Feel free to ask more questions